# Checking a node with an apostrophe in the value

Tags: xml, vba, vbscript, apostrophe

I have a set of code that searches for a person of a particular height that the user selects in a combo box, after which removes all the subjects that don't match in a list. The values for the combo box are like this: `5'0-5'5`. My problem is the apostrophes in the `5'0-5'5` are throwing up errors. Here is my code

```vb
If ComboBox5.Value <> "" Then
    i = 0  

    Do While i <= ListBox26.ListCount - 1
        Set CheckHeight = objDom.SelectSingleNode("//IDNum/LastName[@LName = '" _
            & LastName.Text & "']/FirstName[@FName='" & FirstName.Text _
            & "']/DateOfBirth[@DOB='" & Dob.Text & "']/Height[.='" _
            & ComboBox5.Value & "']")

        If CheckHeight Is Nothing Then
            ListBox26.RemoveItem (i)
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<LastName LName="Rodriguez Jesus Luis">
  <FirstName FName="Armondo">
    <DateOfBirth DOB="7/10/1975">
       <Hair>Black</Hair> 
       <Eyes>Brown</Eyes> 
       <Weight>150 - 175 lbs</Weight> 
       <Height>5'6 - 5'9</Height> 
    </DateOfBirth>
  </FirstName>
</LastName>
```

I have tried replacing one apostrophe "'" with two "''", tried Chr(39), tried `&apos;` but still errors.

I can get it to work if I use `getElementsByTagName` and write a bunch more code to compare and remove, but I was hopping to use the above code as it works with other all the other fields I am using.

The error I am getting is:

> Expected token ']' found 'NUMBER'.
>
> //IDNum/LastName[@LName = 'Rodriguez Jesus Luis']/FirstName[@FName='Armondo']/DateOfBirth[@DOB='7/10/1975']/Height[.='5'-->0<-- - 5'3']

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Updated with error above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes around the string that may contain single quotes. In VBScript nested double quotes in strings are escaped by doubling them:

```vb
Set CheckHeight = objDom.SelectSingleNode("//IDNum/LastName[@LName = '" & _
  LastName.Text & "']/FirstName[@FName='" & FirstName.Text & _
  "']/DateOfBirth[@DOB='" & Dob.Text & _
  "']/Height[.=""" & ComboBox5.Value & """]")
               ^^                       ^^
```

As a side note, your data format is seriously messed up. Your entire hierarchy should rather be attributes of the same node:

```xml
<Person LastName="Rodriguez Jesus Luis"
    FirstName="Armondo"
    DateOfBirth="7/10/1975"
    Hair="Black"
    Eyes="Brown"
    Weight="150 - 175 lbs"
    Height="5'6 - 5'9"
/>
```

Comment: That worked! I figured I needed the double quotes but thought I still needed to include the apostrophe for the node value name. The reason the format is like that is because of other things the program is doing that requires it. Trust me I would rather have it the other way.